# how to divide mongodb data without stopping service

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I got a mongodb running online, which contains about 200 million object, and the file size is about 20GB. And, I found that the insert speed become very slow (about 2000 per sec, and this value is more than 10000 in the beginning). So I decide to divide the data to optimize the insert speed.

I would like the know if i can divide the mongodb data without stopping service, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You just described "sharding".  Luckily for you, MongoDB has nice sharding features out of the box.

Your migration will consist of:

- Create 3 mongo config servers
- Create more than 1 `mongos` router
- Add your current replica set as a shard
- Point your application to connect to your `mongos`
- Configure shard keys your current collections
- Then, you are set to add shards as needed

For detailed instructions, see [10gen's sharding overview](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)

At MongoHQ, we convert replica sets to shards all the time.  So, should be quick, painless, and without downtime.